# Letters not rendering with stb_truetype

Tags: c++, opengl, truetype

I'm working on an OpenGL project and I'm using stb_truetype to render text in my game. The first font I tried (which was a .ttf file which had an OpenType format and TrueType outlines) worked perfectly, the letters and the numbers rendered. When I switched to another font (.ttf with TrueType formatting) the numbers worked but the text didn't. I came across a few sources which claimed that stb_truetype also support .otf file. Currently I'm trying to use the Nexa font (.otf format, OpenType layout, PostScript outlines) which also renders the numbers but not the letters.

Source code for my font.h file:

```
#pragma once
#pragma warning (disable : 4996)

#include <cstdio>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include "VAO.h"
#include <stb/stb_truetype.h>
#include<glm/glm.hpp>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

class Game;
class GLFWwindow;

struct fontVertex {
    glm::vec2 position;
    glm::vec2 texCoords;
};

struct Font {
public:
    VAO fontVAO;
    VBO fontVBO;
    ~Font() {
        if (fvBufferData) {
            delete[]fvBufferData;
        }
    }
    void initFont(const char* filename) {
        uint8_t *ttfBuffer = new uint8_t[1<<20];
        uint8_t *tmpBitmap = new uint8_t[512 * 512]; //res of the bitmap

        fread(ttfBuffer, 1, 1 << 20, fopen(filename, "rb")); //rb makes and writes into a binary file
        stbtt_BakeFontBitmap(ttfBuffer, 0, 128.0f, tmpBitmap, 512, 512, 32, 96, cdata); //there are 96 printable ascii characters, cool stuff

        glGenTextures(1, &fontTexture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fontTexture);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, 512, 512, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tmpBitmap);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fontTexture);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0); //unbind texture

        fvBufferCapacity = 20;
        fvBufferData = new fontVertex[fvBufferCapacity * 6];

        
        fontVAO.Bind();
        fontVBO.Bind();
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(fontVertex) * 6 * fvBufferCapacity, 0, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(fontVertex), 0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(fontVertex), (const void*)offsetof(fontVertex, texCoords));
        fontVAO.Unbind();

    }

    void drawString(float x, float y, const char* text, Shader* fontShader) {
        fontVAO.Bind();
        fontVBO.Bind();

        uint32_t len = strlen(text);
        if (fvBufferCapacity < len) {
            fvBufferCapacity = len;
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(fontVertex) * 6 * fvBufferCapacity, 0, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
            delete[]fvBufferData;
            fvBufferData = new fontVertex[fvBufferCapacity * 6];
        }

        
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fontTexture);
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(fontShader->ID, "u_texture"), 0);

        fontVertex* vData = fvBufferData;
        uint32_t numVertices = 0;
        while (*text) { 
            if (*text >= 32 && *text < 128) {
                stbtt_aligned_quad q;
                stbtt_GetBakedQuad(cdata, 512, 512, *text - 32, &x, &y, &q, 1);

                vData[0].position = glm::vec2(q.x0, q.y0); vData[0].texCoords = glm::vec2(q.s0, q.t0); 
                vData[1].position = glm::vec2(q.x1, q.y0); vData[1].texCoords = glm::vec2(q.s1, q.t0);
                vData[2].position = glm::vec2(q.x1, q.y1); vData[2].texCoords = glm::vec2(q.s1, q.t1);
                vData[3].position = glm::vec2(q.x0, q.y1); vData[3].texCoords = glm::vec2(q.s0, q.t1);
                vData[4].position = glm::vec2(q.x0, q.y0); vData[4].texCoords = glm::vec2(q.s0, q.t0);
                vData[5].position = glm::vec2(q.x1, q.y1); vData[5].texCoords = glm::vec2(q.s1, q.t1);

                vData += 6;
                numVertices += 6;
            }
            ++text;
        }

        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(fontVertex) * numVertices, fvBufferData);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, numVertices);
    }


private:
    stbtt_bakedchar cdata[96];
    GLuint fontTexture;
    fontVertex* fvBufferData;
    uint32_t fvBufferCapacity;
};
```

The shader for the text is pretty standard:

```
//vertex 
#version 330 core

attribute vec2 aPosition;
attribute vec2 aTexture;

frag shaders
out vec2 vTexCoord;

uniform mat4 ModViewProj;

void main(){
    gl_Position = ModViewProj * vec4(aPosition, 0.5f, 1.0f);

    vTexCoord = aTexture;
}
// fragment
#version 330 core

in vec2 vTexCoord;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main(){
    gl_FragColor = vec4(texture(u_texture, vTexCoord).r);
}
```

I'm pretty stumped since I couldn't really find anyone else with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, but managed to solve it by reducing the size of the font from 128.0f to 32.0f in

```
// there are 96 printable ascii characters, cool stuff
stbtt_BakeFontBitmap(ttfBuffer, 0, 128.0f, tmpBitmap, 512, 512, 32, 96, cdata);
```